# Create or retrieve existing Azure Devops group

Tags: azure-devops, terraform-provider-azure

I need to check for existing group and add members to the group. if group does not exists create new group in Azure Devops and add members to it and finally assign permission using terraform using Azure.

Can anyone help with the terraform code using Azure?

Group info, members and permission will be available in Yml file.

I tried to read group name, permission and multiple members. now I am expecting Terra form code for this in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

When there is a group named "groupA" in project "ProTest", add the user to this group and assign the "Contributors" role to this group. I am new to Terraform. When group "groupA" does not exist, `data "azuredevops_group" "groupA"` will fail. I am not sure how to handle it for now. You can further investigate how to solve it, maybe others who are good at it have better suggestions.

```
provider "azuredevops" {
  org_service_url       = "https://dev.azure.com/{DevOps Org name}/"
  personal_access_token = "{PAT}"
}

# Get the project named "ProTest"
data "azuredevops_project" "ProTest" {
  name = "ProTest"
}

data "azuredevops_group" "Contributors" {
  project_id = data.azuredevops_project.ProTest.id
  name       = "Contributors"
}

# Check if the group named "groupA" exists
data "azuredevops_group" "groupA" {
  project_id   = data.azuredevops_project.ProTest.id
  name         = "groupA"
}

resource "azuredevops_group" "groupA" {
  count        = data.azuredevops_group.groupA.id == "" ? 1 : 0 # Use count to conditionally create the resource
  scope        = data.azuredevops_project.ProTest.id
  display_name = "groupA"
  description  = "A custom group for Terraform example"
}

# Add the member with the descriptor "***" to the group named "groupA"
resource "azuredevops_group_membership" "groupA_member" {
  group   = data.azuredevops_group.groupA.descriptor
  members = [
    "***" # The descriptor of the member to be added
  ]
}

# Assign the Contributor role to the group named "groupA"
resource "azuredevops_group_membership" "example" {
  group   = data.azuredevops_group.Contributors.descriptor
  members = [data.azuredevops_group.groupA.descriptor]
}
```

Comment: still i am not clear on this , can anyone assist on this

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to provision a unique azuread group by checking the existing groups and added the members to it.

To manage Azure resources with Terraform, you need to use the Terraform Azure Provider and follow these steps:

- Check if a group already exists
- If not, create a new group
- Add members to the group
- Assign permissions to the group based on a YAML file
  You can use Terraform modules and resources to perform these tasks.

I tried a demo configuration using Terraform, Python and Powershell I was able to provision requirement successfully.

**Terraform configuration:**

##### main.tf:

```
# Provider Configuration
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "external" "group_data" {
  program = ["python", "${path.module}/parse_yaml.py", "${path.module}/group_details.yml"]
}

data "external" "check_group" {
  program = ["Powershell", "${path.module}/check_group.ps1", data.external.group_data.result["group_name"]]
}


# AzureAD Provider
provider "azuread" {}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demorg-vk"
  location = "East US"
}

# Conditionally create the Azure AD group if it does not exist
resource "azuread_group" "example" {
  count = data.external.check_group.result["create_group"] == "true" ? 1 : 0
  display_name       = data.external.group_data.result["group_name"]
  mail_enabled       = false
  security_enabled   = true

}

resource "azuread_group_member" "example_member" {
  for_each         = toset(jsondecode(data.external.group_data.result["members"]))
  group_object_id  = azuread_group.example[0].object_id
  member_object_id = each.value
}
```

##### parse_yaml.py:

```
import yaml
import json
import sys

def read_yaml(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        return yaml.safe_load(file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = read_yaml(sys.argv[1])

    # Convert all non-string values to strings to ensure JSON object format
    formatted_data = {key: json.dumps(value) if isinstance(value, (list, dict)) else str(value) for key, value in data.items()}
    
    print(json.dumps(formatted_data))
```

**check_group.ps1**:

```
param($groupName)

$group = Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "displayName eq '$groupName'"

if ($null -ne $group) {
    Write-Output "{`"create_group`": `"false`"}"
} else {
    Write-Output "{`"create_group`": `"true`"}"
}
```

**group_details.yml:**

```
group_name: "Venakt-app"

members:
  - "8678a431-f3b9-4587-a13b-bc10b101d359"
  - "d0e182b5-0fed-4f44-9916-d3925da28976"

permission:
  name: "Contributor"
  scope: "resource_group"
  resource_group_name: "demorg-vk"
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]